# Cannot see processlist anymore

Tags: mysql

I am importing a large csv file into mysql(30 million rows) and I had another terminal open to show the process list. I used to be able to see the row count on the process list but now, whenever I enter the command "show process list" it hangs. I had 20 million records imported. Do I have to start all over again?
iostat:
    [user@gggggg ~]$ iostat
    Linux 2.6.18-308.4.1.el5

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           5.02    0.00    0.16    0.87    0.00   93.95

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda               2.15         5.31        55.58    8644514   90425752
sda1              0.00         0.00         0.00       2138       5592
sda2              2.15         5.31        55.57    8640178   90419984
sda3              0.00         0.00         0.00       1582        176


top - 14:18:55 up 18 days, 20:00,  2 users,  load average: 2.02, 2.09, 2.06
Tasks: 106 total,   3 running, 103 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.2%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 49.9%id, 49.8%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8174532k total,  7656780k used,   517752k free,   105904k buffers
Swap:  4257216k total,       88k used,  4257128k free,  6958020k cached
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check the filesize from the OS

If the table is called mydb.mytable and it is MyISAM, do this:

```
cd /var/lib/mysql/mydb
watch ls -l mytable.*
```

If the filesize keeps growing, you are fine

Don't forget to check for diskspace

```
df -h
```

If you ran out of diskspace while loading a MyISAM table, mysqld is just sitting there. Why? According to [**MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide Page 408,409 Section 29.2 bulletpoint 11**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328127) says:

> If you run out of disk space while adding rows to a MyISAM table, no
>   error occurs. The server suspends the operation until space becomes
>   available, and then completes the operation.

Therefore, if the data partition is out of diskspace, you must free up some space so mysqld can conitnue the `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

If everything seems frozen, you may have to kill mysqld as follows:

```
IDTOKILL=`ps -ef | grep mysqld_safe | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
kill -9 ${IDTOFKILL}
IDTOKILL=`ps -ef | grep mysqld | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
kill -9 ${IDTOFKILL}
```

Then, check your diskspace

Comment: So should I cancel the load data infile?

Comment: Two questions : 1) Are you out of diskspace? 2) Is the table still growing?

Comment: I can't even check for disk space since it hangs if I try to go to the folder where all my tables are. I cant check if the table is growing either. What I'm worried about is that I will have to kill the thread again and that will take forever.

Comment: Yeah I did that. I can't even access the folder where my db is since it hangs. All other folders I can access. I also can't start another mysql connection as that hangs as well. Right now, all I see is the load data infile command with a cursor after it. I am not sure if it is still doing anything.

Comment: OK next 3 questions : Are you experiencing high load? Can you run `iostat` at all? Can you run `top`?

Comment: df -h also hangs i can only see  a few files and their sizes

Comment: Run it as it appears. IDTOKILL captures the process ID of mysqld_safe, then captures the process ID of mysqld.

Comment: New question : Are you running mysql in the Cloud, VMWare, or  bare-metal machine?